# Covert date string into date format excel

Tags: excel, date, format

Is it possible to convert to date text like this

```
2014-10-24-06.59.00.000000
```

into format like `10/24/2014  6:59` in excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=--LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-"," ",3),".",":"),19)
```

and custom format the cell as

> mm/dd/yyyy h:mm

If that doesn't work, there may be some issues with international date settings, and we will need a more complex formula.

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,6,2),MID(A1,9,2))+TIME(MID(A1,12,2),MID(A1,15,2),MID(A1,17,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=MID(B3,6,2)&"/"&MID(B3,9,2)&"/"&LEFT(B3,4)&" "&MID(B3,12,2)&":"&MID(B3,15,2)
```

Where B3 is the cell where you have your text format. i.e **2014-10-24-06.59.00.000000**